# TypeScript: not sure if I typed this promise-returning function correctly

Tags: typescript

I have a util function that fetches a list of resources at an endpoint. I wanted to properly type this function.

```
type item = {
  id: number
  name: string
}

export default function fetchItems(): Promise<item[]> {
  return fetch(ENDPOINT).then(async (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      const json = await response.json()
      return json
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Unknown Error'))
    }
  })
}
```

Right now there is no type errors for this function, but I wonder if for the returning type i.e.
`Promise<item[]>` I should add a union type that also contains the error since it can reject with that errors, something like `Promise<item[] | Error>` or the current version is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not keep track of types for possible Promise rejection reasons. (Similarly, TypeScript does not keep track of types for ordinary synchronous `try`/`catch` errors). If you have a Promise in TypeScript, all you can do is denote the type of the resolve value; the reject value is not (and cannot) be typed.

For example:

```
const prom = Promise.reject('foo');
```

gives a type of `Promise<never>`.

Your current implementation is just fine; the `'Unknown Error'` in the rejection doesn't go anywhere in the type system, as far as TS is concerned.